# Yo won't run due to npm ERR! EEXIST

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

I try to run `gulp-angular` via `yo`:

```
yo gulp-angular
```

All works perfectly fine until this line:

```
Binary is fine; exiting <------ ERROR STARTS AFTER THIS LINE
npm ERR! EEXIST, open 'C:\Users\aviel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\0e13ca0b-cache-through2-0-6-3-package-tgz.lock'

File exists: C:\Users\aviel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\0e13ca0b-cache-through2-0-6-3-package-tgz.lock
Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd c:\yo\angular-project
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path C:\Users\aviel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\0e13ca0b-cache-through2-0-6-3-package-tgz.lock
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
```

I'v tried(suggested [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6238)):

```
rm -rf ~/.npm && npm cache clearn
```

But it didn't worked, I'v also reinstall(node, npm, yo, bower, gulp, generator-gulp-angular) but same error.

Also I'v tried:

```
bower cache clean
npm cache clean
```

My npm version is the latest version for my OS(**Windows 8.1 Enterprise N(x64)**) so `npm update npm -g` won't help(although I did try).

Some info:

- Windows 8.1 Enterprise N-x64
- Node version 0.10.35-x64
- npm version 1.4.28

If anyone got any idea I will be very thankful.

Comment: I got a similar problem using 32-bit on 64-bit Windows 7. Clean didn't fix it, but upgrading node did.

Comment: Have you tried making sure the directory is removed when you clean the cache or just going in and manually removing that directory?  That will get you back up and running, won't necessarily tell you what actually happened though.

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing this problem at ubuntu.

I tried many ways to install npm package.

but this problem solved by updating my nodejs

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

after this, now install npm package installed smoothly.